# PHP SEARCH and then INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, search, insert

I'm a relative novice when it comes to PHP and after doing some searching I can't seem to find an answer to my question.

What I have is pretty basic, two tables 'person' and 'case'. I'm able to insert and search for a person (albeit it took me sometime to get it working!). Now when it comes to a 'Case' I need to firstly search for a person, I want the search results to remain populate in the form, the user then adds the rest of the case information to the form and then submits it. I've tried combining my both codes together but I'm still without success.

Even if I could find a way of the output to remain populated in the form that would be a big step forward for me. I've left the output as print so the search results show up on the page. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The current search and insert code is below:

```
    <?php

    include 'connection.php';
    $output ='';
    //collect

    if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $searchq = $_POST['search'];
        $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM person WHERE forename LIKE '%$searchq%' OR surname LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("Could not search");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if ($count == 0) {
            $output = 'There was no search results';
        }else{
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                $firstname = $row['forename'];
                $lastname = $row['surname'];

                $output .= '<div>'.$firstname.' '.$lastname.'</div>';
        }
    }
    }
    ?>

    <form action="basicsearch.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for Persons..." onkeydown="searchq()1" />
        <input type="submit" value=">>"/>

    </form>

    <?php print("$output");?>



<?php
$forename = $surname = $dateofbirth = $postcode = $addresslineone = $addresslinetwo = $towncity = $contactnumber="";
$forenameErr = $surnameErr = $dateofbirthErr = $postcodeErr = $addresslineoneErr = $addresslinetwoErr = $towncityErr = $contactnumberErr = "";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST") {
    $valid = true; 

    if (empty($_POST["forename"])) {
        $forenameErr = "*First name is required";
        $valid = false;
    }
    else {
        $forename = test_input($_POST["forename"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["surname"])) {
        $surnameErr = "*Last name is required";
        $valid = false;
    }
    else {
        $surname = test_input($_POST["surname"]);
    }

    //only testing forename/surname at the moment

    if($valid){
        include  'datasubmitted.php';  
        exit;
    }
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
    <div class="label">*First Name:
        <div class="txtbox">
            <input name="forename" type="text" id="txt" placeholder="Enter Your First Name." value="<?php echo $surname; ?>"/>
            <span class="error"><p></p><?php echo  $forenameErr; ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="label">Last Name:
        <div class="txtbox">
            <input name="surname" type="text" id="txt" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name." value="<?php echo $surname; ?>"/>
            <span class="error"><p></p><?php echo $surnameErr; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
</form> 

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
    <div class="label">*First Name:
        <div class="txtbox">
            <input name="forename" type="text" id="txt" placeholder="Enter Your First Name." value="<?php echo $surname; ?>"/>
            <span class="error"><p></p><?php echo  $forenameErr; ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="label">Last Name:
        <div class="txtbox">
            <input name="surname" type="text" id="txt" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name." value="<?php echo $surname; ?>"/>
            <span class="error"><p></p><?php echo $surnameErr; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

All the best,
Chris

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for posting code, that's a big help. However, it's not quite clear from your question what this code is doing now. Would you try to clarify the current behavior you're observing, and the desired behavior?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sure, I have two seperate codes, one for inserting and one for searching. The desired functionality I want it to be able to search for a client and once the search is complete it will populate other text boxes. So for instance searching for surname would then populate other boxes such as forename, postcode, date of birth etc, I'm unsure how I would do this. From there I would then combine the results of the search results with additional information the user puts in the case fields.

Comment: @noa So first instance you have a client table which stores client information and a case table which stores case information. When submitting a case you have to look up the client first find their details and then type in the case details and save. I currently have an echo there that lists all the returned criteria from the search as a list, instead I would like that to pull through into the form's text boxes so the text box surname would be populate with the users surname, date of birth with the search results date of birth etc. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hopefully someone more familiar with PHP can help. What you're saying makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your SQL code might still be vulnerable to SQL injection, despite your application of preg_replace(). It's better to use a parameterized query on input sanitized with PHP filter_input functions. (This is much less likely to fail meaningfully than a hand-built input sanitizer.)

I can't see your INSERT statement. You're using MySQL so you might consider first doing an INSERT IGNORE, followed by a SELECT.

But even this suggestion fails to scratch the surface of a subject that is more complex than it first appears. What are you going to do if you have two clients who are namesakes (have the same name, but are different people)? How are you going to handle potential mis-spellings of names, and the resulting duplicate records? Can there be many cases per person?
These are all both system issues, and also user-interface ergonomics issues. Only careful user-interface design and system design can effectively overcome these problems!
If you're dealing with a database that could potentially have thousands of records, you will need to think carefully about these issues. If you're "only" dealing with hundreds of people; then this might not be a problem!

Please tell us more…

Comment: Thank you for you reply, a lot of good questions that I hadn't considered. I was considering either getting the user to search via surname and ID or print the results into a table and the user can then modify the user from the table generated. The system is only to handle a small amount of clients. A client can have many cases though. I think I need to research into this more, but I'm open to any suggestions if at all possible, still very much coming to terms with SQL/PHP. Thanks again, Chris.

Comment: If your system is "only" designed to handle a small number of clients; then it might be appropriate to have the person selected from a list/table of hyperlinks (which might be filtered/ordered by first name or by surname); and then have a separate person-detail page; where you show an editing form for personal details, a list/table of cases, and a form for entering the details of any new cases. Based on your PHP code, I think this type of solution should definitely be possible for you!

Comment: Yeah it's very much a small system. Your suggestions does seem the most logical way to go about it. So list the entire Client table on a page with a surname filter and a link next to each customer that says 'select'. This would then open a different page with a form for adding the case, at the top of the case there would be 'Client ID' which will be field from the using pressing 'select' from the previous screen. The user would then fill the rest of the form out with case details. With the client ID link the client to the case. Am I being too naive or ambitious with that?

Comment: No, neither too naive nor too ambitious. Looks about right to me!